# How to fill malloc'd buffer with fread?

Tags: assembly, malloc, nasm, fread

Apologies for long code, but such as it is with assembly:

```
SECTION .text       ; code
    extern _fclose
    extern _fopen
    extern _fread
    extern _fseek
    extern _ftell
    extern _malloc
    extern _printf

    global _main

    _main:
        ;   stash base stack pointer
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp,    esp

        push    DWORD   fname
        push    DWORD   mopf
        push    DWORD   mcls
        call    _printf
        add     esp,    12          ; clean up stack use

        ;   open file
        push    DWORD   fread
        push    DWORD   fname
        call    _fopen
        add     esp,    8

        cmp     eax,    0
        jnz     .valid

        push    DWORD   mfnf
        push    DWORD   mopf
        jmp     .error

        .valid:
        mov     [fh],   eax

        ;   output result
        push    DWORD   [fh]
        push    DWORD   mopf
        push    DWORD   mret
        call    _printf
        add     esp,    12

        push    DWORD   [fh]
        push    DWORD   mskf
        push    DWORD   mcld
        call    _printf
        add     esp,    12

        ;   C:
        ;   fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);    ; set up constants: SEEK_END, SEEK_SET, etc.
        push    DWORD   [SEEK_END]
        push    DWORD   0               ; 0L
        push    DWORD   [fh]            ; f_hndl
        call    _fseek                  ; ret [eax]: 0 okay; otherwise 1
        add     esp,    12              ; reset stack pointer

        cmp     eax,    0
        je      .success

        push    DWORD   mske
        push    DWORD   mskf
        jmp     .error

        .success:
        ;   output result
        push    DWORD   eax
        push    DWORD   mskf
        push    DWORD   mret
        call    _printf
        add     esp,    12

        ;   C:
        ;   sz = ftell(fp);             ; result to eax
        push    DWORD   [fh]
        call    _ftell
        add     esp,    4

        mov     [fsz],  eax

        ;   output result
        push    DWORD   [fsz]
        push    DWORD   mszf
        push    DWORD   mcld
        call    _printf
        add     esp,    12

        ;   allocate buffer
        ;   C:
        ;   p* = malloc(size)
        push    DWORD   [fsz]
        call    _malloc
        add     esp,    4

        mov     DWORD[buffer],    eax

        ;   read file
        ;   size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
        push    DWORD   [fh]
        push    DWORD   1
        push    DWORD   [fsz]
        push    DWORD   [buffer]
        call    _fread
        add     esp,    16

        push    DWORD   eax
        push    DWORD   mrdf
        push    DWORD   mcld
        call    _printf
        add     esp,    12

        jmp     .done

        .error:
        push    DWORD   merr
        call    _printf
        add     esp,    12

        .done:
        push    DWORD   [fh]
        call    _fclose

        push    DWORD   eax
        push    DWORD   mclf
        push    DWORD   mcld
        call    _printf
        add     esp,    16

        ;   restore base stack pointer
        mov     esp,    ebp
        pop     ebp

        ret

SECTION .bss        ; uninitialized data
    fh:     resd    1
    fsz:    resd    1
    buffer: resb    20
```

current output:

> [FILE] call [open]: d:\asmplus\tsources\s1.txt
>   [FILE] ret [open]: 2002397536
>   [FILE] call [seek]: 2002397536
>   [FILE] ret [seek]: 0
>   [FILE] call [size]: 6
>   [FILE] call [read]: 0
>   [FILE] call [close]: 0

*corrected output based on @Michael's response*
I added an additional output (not shown in code above) that produces the following:

> [FILE] ret [╨9=]: 6

... which follows the `fread` call:

```
push    DWORD   [fsz]
push    DWORD   [buffer]
push    DWORD   mret
call    _printf
add     esp,    12
```

<strike>Apparently `[fsz]` changed from the correct value of 6 (bytes) to the length of `[buffer]` (20 bytes) plus 2.</strike>

Based on the definition `size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)` I expect `EAX` to contain the number of bytes read.

Relative snippets:

```
;   allocate buffer
;   C:
;   p* = malloc(size)
push    DWORD   [fsz]
call    _malloc
add     esp,    4

mov     DWORD[bfr],    eax

;   read file
;   size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
push    DWORD   [fh]      ; FILE* stream (file handle)
push    DWORD   1         ; size_t nmemb
push    DWORD   [fsz]     ; size_t size
push    DWORD   [buffer]  ; void* ptr (buffer previously malloc'd)
call    _fread
add     esp,    16
```

I assumed from the [description here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm):

> Parameters:
>       * ptr -- This is the pointer to a block of memory with a minimum size
>      of size*nmemb bytes
>       * size -- This is the size in bytes of each element to be read.
>       * nmemb -- This is the number of elements, each one with a size of size bytes.
>       * stream -- This is the pointer to a FILE object that specifies an input stream.

... that `size` would be 1 byte (char size) and `nmemb` would be the size of the buffer malloc'd.

What am I doing wrong first in calling and assigning the `malloc`'d buffer and, second, in filling it with a call to `fread`?

**Update**
After adding code to seek back to the beginning of the source file, I am reading the bytes. However, there seems to be something that now raises a couple of questions. Here is the output:

> [FILE] call [read]: 1
>   [FILE] ret [1 + 2;r]: 6

The file s1.txt contains `1 + 2;` which is 6 bytes correctly reported on the 2nd line. But `fread` is apparently reporting that it only read 1 byte? And should I use `fsz` + 1 in the call to `fread` to get rid of the `r` in `[1 + 2;r]`?

Comment: You have positioned to the end of the file by using `fseek`, so you won't get any bytes read. Better reposition to the beginning of the file ;)

Comment: D'oh ... I feel dumber now than when I began this journey. Fortunately I can comfortably laugh at myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not seeking back to the start of the file before reading it. So if you try and read from the end, you'll get 0 bytes.

ie. add in:

```
push    DWORD   0               ; SEEK_SET = 0
push    DWORD   0               ; 0L
push    DWORD   [fh]            ; f_hndl
call    _fseek                  ; ret [eax]: 0 okay; otherwise 1
add     esp,    12              ; reset stack pointer
```

> The file s1.txt contains 1 + 2; which is 6 bytes correctly reported on
>   the 2nd line. But fread is apparently reporting that it only read 1
>   byte?

No, fread is reporting that it read 1 structure, of 6 bytes. You probably want this:

```
    push    DWORD   [fh]
    push    DWORD   [fsz]
    push    DWORD   1                ; Note.. swapped!!!
    push    DWORD   [buffer]
    call    _fread
    add     esp,    16
```

For the bytes at the end of the buffer -- you are reading 6 bytes from the file, but printf needs a null terminated string. If you want to fix this, allocate an extra byte of space, and set the last byte to '\0' before calling printf.

Comment: Okay, this has solved the initial problem, but now I am seeing something strange although I am seeing the output of the file (1 + 2;) See edited question (bottom - update) for explanation.

Comment: Something strange? Will need more info if you need help :)

Comment: Edited the answer to include all of the questions you had; but not sure if you would have got pinged for the update, so replying here :)

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) for `printf`:

> **Return Value**
>   On success, the total number of characters written is returned.

Based on that, this code is incorrect:

```
    call    _printf
    add     esp,    12

    mov     [fsz],  eax
```

What you're saving in `fsz` is the return value from `printf`, i.e. the length of the string `"[FILE] call [size]: 6"`.

Comment: Okay, I've corrected the placement of the `mov` statement so that the output is correct. But this still doesn't resolve the problem of filling the buffer. :)